# how to get the exact request used for a tile in ipyleaflet?

Tags: tile-layer, ipyleaflet

I'm building a map using ipyleaflet and world imagery wayback WMS data. I want to display the metadata associated to each image when the map is clicked so that user know what they are looking at.

I'm using the following to display the map:

```py
xyz = 'https://wayback.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/world_imagery/wmts/1.0.0/default028mm/mapserver/tile/47963/{z}/{y}/{x}'

from ipyleaflet import TileLayer, Map

layer = TileLayer(url = xyz, name="2023-06-29 wayback")

m = Map(center=[-12.691253472166476, -55.13488769531251], zoom=10)
m.add(layer)
m
```

To display the metadata, I would need to use the metadata using this url: [https://metadata.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery_Metadata_{map_id}/MapServer/z/x/y](https://metadata.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery_Metadata_%7Bmap_id%7D/MapServer/z/x/y)
required parameter are:

- `map_id`: the same as the one I use
- `z`: is the zoom easy as well
- `x` and `y` from the tile.

How can I get the associated tile x,y parameter when I click on the map ?

```py
def handle_click(**kwargs):
    if kwargs.get("type") == "click":
        # do something clever

m.on_interaction(handle_click)
```